# don’t use “the same” in that manner

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, word-choice

Here is what I wrote to someone

*For the following companies submission is done on Greenhouse and Aavia through the link. When submitted through those channels, is it ok to send them an email informing of the same?*

I was told don’t use “the same” in that manner. We don’t do that in the US

How much of its true and I never heard that before

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are talking about. What is submission, what are "companies", what are Greenhouse and Aavia? Who will be sent an email?

Comment: I would agree with whoever told you that. Using "the same" to mean "what I just said" or "what came before" sounds like someone trying to imitate a bad TV lawyer.

Comment: "informing of the same" is stilted. It's also ambiguous. Do you mean "For the following companies, submission is done on Greenhouse and Aavia through the link. **Upon submission** through those channels, is it ok to send **the submitter** a **confirmation email**?"? In the original sentences, "When submitted" doesn't currently refer to anything, and "them" is also ambiguous.

Comment: the following companies-submission(of something) is done  on the Greenhouse, Applicant tracking system & recruiting software, and Aavia Healthcare Apps- through the link- (read; link on App) When it has been submitted via that route. *Now the question* **is it ok to send them an email informing them of that?** No doubt the question being raised is **Should they be contacted through the App or via e-mail**.

Answer (score 1):

I think your sentence is fine, it is easy to understand and fairly normal  business style writing. Why the melodramatics regarding what your first sentence means I do not know? the sentence is understandable, however it is hardly essential to understand that, to comment on the use of "*informing of the same*?"

> You use same to refer to something that has already been mentioned in a document such as a business letter or bill. Ref [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/same)

> When submitted through those channels, is it ok to send them an email informing them of **that**?

As for the Americans it is defined in their dictionary;

> same pronoun; something or someone previously mentioned or described —often used with the or a demonstrative (such as that, those) in both senses [MERRIAM-WEBSTER DICTIONARY](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/same)

That; pronoun; used as the subject or object of a verb to show which person or thing you are referring to, or to add information about a person or thing just mentioned. It is used for both people and things. It can often be left out:

---

> However who am I to argue with American's on the use of our language. **If they say it is not used it is not used**.

Comment: *Same* used as a pronoun is perfectly understandable for an American. It shouldn’t have an article, though